# Mojolicious: DBIx::Class::Row::get_column(): No such column ''

Tags: mojolicious

If you were using code like below, to get all the parameters out of a HTML form in a Mojolicious application, you may get the error  *No such column*.

Code causing this error:

```
  my $fields;
  foreach ($c->req->body_params->param) {
    $fields->{"$_"} = $c->req->body_params->param("$_");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to an update in Mojolicious, which [removed multi-name support from various methods](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Upgrading#multi-name-parameter-retrieval).

The above code should be changed to the much simpler form:

```
my $fields = $c->req->body_params->to_hash;
```